# Favorites Module - Browser Problem

Tags: ee2, solspace

I have installed and managed to get the favorites module to work on a project I'm developing.

I can save and remove favorites.

I was doing this in Chrome and successfully viewed my favorites assigned to my user.

However just checked in other browsers and my favorites simply don't show up.

Has anyone come across this problem before ?

Please help.

Comment: Please post relevant portions of your template and the output you are getting.

Comment: Also please mention the version of Favorites and EE that you are using. For completeness, are you adding/removing favorites through ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Did you login on every browser? I believe the default setting for Favorites is private.

Comment: Ye I believe this was the problem. I needed to login within every browser in order to get it to work, which is how it essentially should work anyway. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for all the replies guys :)